# doctrine 2 how to load doctrine_pager

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

im trying to use the doctrine pager but its errored:

Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine_Pager' not found

code:

$page = 1;
    $results_per_page = 10;

```
$pager = new Doctrine_Pager(
                $query,
                $page,
                $results_per_page
);
$results = $pager->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
$num_results = $results->getNumResults();
```

i usually call doctrine EM like this:

```
 $this->_doctrine = Zend_Registry::get('doctrineEm');
    $query = $this->_doctrine->createQueryBuilder()
```

how would i load this doctrine  pager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its my understanding that the pager from 1.2 has been removed from doctrine2.

However, you can add "doctrine extensions" to the ORM which will give you that functionality.

https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions